# C function call strange error

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

I'm trying to call a function in main for the different programs (Q2-3 and Q4) but I'm getting an error during compiling. in my main I have
prog1 ();  [it says "previous implicit declaration of prog1 was here"]
then there is a function of the same name at the very end
void prog1()
{ [it says "conflicting types for prog1"] and yes it just says it on a line where the only thing is {

the [] are just what I typed here not what is in my code. If you need more parts of my code let me know. My program is written in C not C++

Comment: Showing code would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't give a prototype for `prog1()`.

If it has for example the following signature

```
char *prog1(void);
```

and you don't give a prototype but call it from `main()`, then you define it later with the mentioned signature, the implicitly declared prototype which is `int prog1()` conflicts with the definition.

Just add a prototype before `main()`.